# Making the CSS properties of an element different on every page. E.g Color

Tags: css, stylesheet

So pretty much what I want is to make something like this. http://www.woodbuffalo.ab.ca/Visiting/Accommodation-and-Dining.htm

See how the border around the content area changes depending on the part of menu you're in?

I have an idea in mind, but I want to know if there are easier ways to do this.

Edit: okay, my idea: I'm not even sure if this would work, it would be to make a different class for the content menu depending on what category that page belongs to, and then style these classes in CSS with the colours I want. But I feel like there's a better approach for this that I don't know.

Comment: _I have an idea in mind, but I want to know if there are easier ways_ - how would we know? We're not mindreaders.

Comment: This question doesn't supply of any programming, and it's also asking people to do work for you, and it doesn't show any of the attempts you made. I suggest editing the question.

Comment: please dont use SO for chatting around about ideas and conversation without results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID the pages separately and then style the certain elements in question separately while distinguishing them with the unique page Id's.  see the example below.

```
/* Example */

#page-id Element-in-question {

Whatever_you_want_to_happen_goes_here!

}
```

**HTML**

```
/*  Home page HTML */

<body id="home">

<h1>Home</h1>

</body>


/*  About page HTML */

<body id="about">

  <h1>Abou</h1>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
       #home h1  {
        color: red;
    }

  #about h1 {
   color: green;
}
```

With the above example,  h1s on the home page will be red while h1s on the about page will be green.

**Wordpress/PHP**

If the pages are dynamically generated you can implement the body_class template tag into a theme just by adding `<?php body_class(); ?>` to your opening body tag as shown below. That assigns unique classes to all the pages.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: If that works, choose it as the answers. Thanks

Comment: If we're going to do it using PHP what would the code look like?

Comment: @TheMrGhost I've added a section in the answers that covers how this can be achieved in wordpress.